# Convert AsyncTask to RxJava in Android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, rx-java

First, I'm brand new to java on android studio, and trying to use codes from github using asyncTask. However AsyncTask is deprecated so it needs to be replaced with rxJava according to what I was suggested. I'd appreciate if someone help convert the code below to rxJava. Thank you.

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("DownloadTask","DownloadTask : " + data);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }
```

Comment: Just so you know, it doesn't need to be replaced by RxJava.  AsyncTask was deprecated because it doesn't work like you think it does (all AsyncTasks run on a single thread) and that because of that it's actually terrible to use for networking (a single task will block all others until done).  In Kotlin it should be replaced by coroutines.  In Java, it can be replaced most easily by just creating your own thread,

Comment: Also, this was bad code to begin with.  There never should have been two AsyncTasks here.  It should have been one task that did both things.  The second task never caused anything but extra thread switching to occur.